# mac how to override fn key in intellij usage?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, key-bindings

So, I've remapped my `fn` key to be `Command`. Thus, when I do `fn+Enter`, spotlight search pops up.

The problem is: on intellij, my autcomplete keymap is `fn+enter` as well. But everytime I try to use it, the spotlight search  annoyingly pops up.

How do I work around this? I'd very much like to have `fn+enter` as my autocomplete binding on intellij.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the shortcut to display Spotlight in `System Preferences... | Keyboard | Shortcuts | Spotlight | Show Spotlight search`.